# how to list the audio files in a Listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I am new to this android application development.

I have a audio files in a particular directory. I want to list the those audio files in a listView.

please tell me how to do this activity.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a [File](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object representing your directory on the SDcard and call appropriate File#list() variant to get list of all the files in that directory. You will get names of the files in a String[].
2. Create an Adapter class and pass this String array to it. Make a ListView and back it up by this custom Adapter.You can refer examples in API demos or [this](http://www.androidguys.com/2008/07/14/fancy-listviews-part-one/) tutorial for the same